# How to retrive Json data from cookie in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

This is a add to cart to cookies, but i am not clear this one, also when i click refresh and addtocart onclick function, all cookie value will be overwrittened,

my aimed solution is, 
cookievalue = [{id:1,price:33,qty:1},{id:1,price:33,qty:1},{id:1,price:33,qty:1}];

var cartstring = {};
        var jsonstring = [];

```
var addtocart = (function(id,price,qty)
{
        cartstring.id = id;
        cartstring.price = price;
        cartstring.qty = qty;
        /* Also check here whether the cookie having data then the new value will be pushed and then inserted to cookie */
        jsonstring = JSON.stringify(cartstring); 

        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3600 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = "cartObj=" + jsonstring + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
});
```

Thank so much for your attention sir/mam.

Comment: share some code you tried, or be ready to get downvoted

Comment: Also: welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of how to write and read json data

```
const data = {
    int: 22,
    obj: { name: 'bar' },
    arr: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
}


//  write cookie
document.cookie = `json=${JSON.stringify(data)}`; 

//  read all cookie values
console.log(document.cookie)

//  read json string value from cookie
console.log(document.cookie.split('json=')[1].split(';')[0]); 

//  parse json string value to object
console.log(JSON.parse(document.cookie.split('json=')[1].split(';')[0]));
```